# App crash on loading dependent libraries while making xcframework

Tags: ios, swift, xcframework

I am making a xcframework. In my framework project, I have added cocoa pods like Alamofire, Realm, and more. When I integrate my xcframework in my application, the application crashes showing following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s9Alamofire10HTTPMethodO3getyA2CmFWC
  
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E81F9FBA-3876-4959-B675-B89A4EC0257A/BykesPod.app/Frameworks/MYFRAMEWORK.framework/MYFRAMEWORK
  
Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E81F9FBA-3876-4959-B675-B89A4EC0257A/DEMOAPP.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
 
in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E81F9FBA-3876-4959-B675-B89A4EC0257A/DEMOAPP.app/Frameworks/MYFRAMEWORK.framework/MYFRAMEWORK

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

Following is the pod file of my framework project

```
target 'MYFRAMEWORK' do
    project './MYFRAMEWORK.xcodeproj'
      pod 'Realm'
      pod 'RealmSwift'
      pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8'
      pod 'MBProgressHUD','1.1.0'
      pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

I have added following dependencies in my podspec file:

```
s.dependency "Realm"
s.dependency "RealmSwift"
s.dependency "Alamofire","~> 4.8.2"
s.dependency "MBProgressHUD","~> 1.1.0"
s.dependency "SwiftyJSON"
```

Following is the pod file of my demo application:

```
target 'DEMOAPP' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'PODNAME'
end
```

Following are the commands from which I am making xcframeworks

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace MYFRAMEWORK.xcworkspace  -scheme MYFRAMEWORK -sdk iphoneos -archivePath "archives/0/ios_device.xcarchive" BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild archive -workspace MYFRAMEWORK.xcworkspace  -scheme MYFRAMEWORK -sdk iphonesimulator -archivePath "archives/0/ios_simulators.xcarchive" BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework archives/0/ios_device.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MYFRAMEWORK.framework -framework archives/0/ios_simulators.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MYFRAMEWORK.framework -output build/MYFRAMEWORK.xcframework
```

Note: My code xcode version is 12.4

Comment: Did you found any solution to this?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara yes see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this problem is to enable following option in Target Build setting

1. Open Target build settings in Xcode
2. search for `Build Libraries for distribution`
3. change it to "Yes".

**Note:** If you are distributing Project/Library/Framework and it contains/depends on `Cocoapods` add following script into your destination Project where framework is integrated.
This script enables `Build Libraries for distribution` for all installing `Cocoapod` dependencies.

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the solution I found was to make the "Build Libraries for distribution" flag true in the Pods project of my application. See attached screenshot.

[image: Build Libraries for distribution flag]